# How to install moveit on fuerte?

Tags: ros, moveit, installation, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the title suggest I'm trying to install ***moveit*** for motion planning purposes on ROS Fuerte. In [this](http://moveit.ros.org/download.html) page it's written that it is available for fuerte only from source. However in the [instructions](http://moveit.ros.org/installation.html) page, there is nothing about fuerte. How should I do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47877/how-to-install-moveit-on-fuerte?/) by [Pouya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3552/pouya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-11-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ibrahim](https://answers.ros.org/users/331/ibrahim/) on 2012-11-09**:
If you figure it out I'd be really happy to know how you did it. I'm also trying to get moveit to work but I'm trying to use Groovy beta packages and not having a lot of success either.

**Comment by [Pouya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3552/pouya/) on 2012-11-12**:
There are two packages that I should test: ros-fuerte-moveit-core and ros-fuerte-moveit-msgs. I don't know if they do the job or not. Have you tried with these two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you try replacing all groovy packages with the corresponding fuerte versions? You might run into build problems but there is a certain chance that it works.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pouya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3552/pouya/) on 2012-11-12**:
I tried but there are several packages that have no corresponding in fuerte. Don't think it will really work.